# pd.to_datetime convert non date strings to date

Tags: python, pandas

In dataframe I have column "`_date_`" . This column contains lots of strings, some of which are dates. I'm trying to convert the strings that contain dates into datetimes.

I have used pd.to_datetime with errors='coerce', however part of string cells are also converted to date, for example "--70--" is converted to "2070-01-01"

How can I prevent pandas to not convert not date strings to date.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'_date_': ['22 Jun 2023', '123', '--99--', "--70--", "b", "c", "d"]})

df["_date_"] = pd.to_datetime(df['_date_'], errors='coerce')
df['_date_']

0   2023-06-22
1          NaT
2   1999-01-01
3   2070-01-01
4          NaT
5          NaT
6          NaT
Name: _date_, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: You could filter the column first with regex. This way you can get rid of the unwanted datetimes (such as "--70--", "b", etc. After that, simply apply your `to_datetime` and you're good.

Comment: Here I have shown just few entries of column. Not all entries that should not be converted to date have format "--number--", so applying filter with regex will not solve the problem. My question was why pandas treats this kind of string as a date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a specific date format, then **be specific**:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['_date_'], format='%d %b %Y', errors='coerce')
```

Else, you can replace a specific unwanted character (here `-` on start of string, but not in the middle to enable correct parsing of something like `2022-08-29`) to ensure the date will be invalid:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['_date_'].str.replace('^-', 'invalid', regex=True),
               errors='coerce')
```

output:

```
0   2023-06-22
1          NaT
2          NaT
3          NaT
4          NaT
5          NaT
6          NaT
Name: _date_, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: The date format for this column is not known. Also not all entries that should not be converted to date have "--number--" format. My question was why pandas treats this kind of strings as a date

Comment: I guess the "why?" is because the function tries to match as many cases as possible when no format is provided.